# How can I check that my LAN card is VLAN capable?

Tags: setup, vlan

I am trying to figure out if my PC LAN card is VLAN capable or not.

To be precise I want to check if my lan card can c

1. Can I receive VLAN tagged traffic
2. If I can receive , after that can I untag the VLAN tagged traffic?
3. Can send out traffic VLAN tagged traffic from my PC?

If someone can provide the conceptual answers and the practical setup to check those, I would be grateful.

My PC is running Ubuntu 12.04. Just for info.

Answer (score 1):

Lookup the manufacturer and specifications of the NIC.  See if they mention 802.1q compatibility in hardware drivers.  If that isn't possible, here is a complete [article](http://www.stgraber.org/2012/01/04/networking-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) on turning on and testing 802.1q (VLAN tagging) in Ubuntu

Comment: The questions you are asking would require pages of information to answer.  This is the stuff books are made of.  This is a Q&A site.  This is not a site for people to donate their time to do free network engineering for you.  I humbly point out there is a huge difference.